# How to use VirtualBox on a Ubuntu Server without any desktop

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox on Ubuntu Server 16.04. This server has not any installed desktop. Also we don't want to install any desktop on it. Is there any way to create and manage virtual machine using VirtualBox with command line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These are the steps for creating an Ubuntu virtual machine:

1. Create virtual machine

   ```
   VBoxManage createvm --name Ubuntu10.10
   ```
2. Create hard disk

   ```
   VBoxManage createhd --filename Ubuntu10.10 --size 5120
   ```
3. Register the virtual machine

   ```
   VBoxManage registervm '/home/user/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu10.10/Ubuntu10.10.vbox'
   ```
4. Set OS type

   ```
   VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu10.10 --ostype Ubuntu
   ```
5. Set the memory or RAM (in MB)

   ```
   VBoxManage modify Ubuntu10.10 --memory 512
   ```
6. Create a storage controller

   ```
   VBoxManage storagectl Ubuntu10.10 --name IDE --add ide --controller PIIX4 --bootable on
   ```

   - Note: `--add` is for adding type of system bus like `ide/sata/scsi/floppy`

     - `--controller` is for choosing type of chipset
     - `--bootable` says if the controller is bootable
7. Attach the storage

   ```
   VBoxManage storageattach Ubuntu10.10 --storagectl IDE --port 0 --device 0 --type hdd --medium "filename"
   ```

   - Note: `filename` is the ISO image location, like

     ```
     /home/user/Downloads/ubuntu-10.10-desktop-i386.iso
     ```
8. Add features you may need

   ```
   VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu10.10 --vram 128 --accelerate3d on --audio alsa --audiocontroller ac97
   ```
9. set the type of networking

   ```
   VBoxManage modifyvm Ubuntu10.10 --nic1 nat --nictype1 82540EM --cableconnected1 on
   ```

   - Note: options include `none`, `null`, `nat`, `bridged`, `intnet`, `hostonly`, `vde`
10. Start the virtual machine

    ```
    VBoxManage startvm Ubuntu10.10
    ```

#### In summary

1. create a named virtual device
2. create a virtual hard drive
3. register the virtual machine
4. set OS type
5. set RAM
6. create and set storage controller
7. Attach storage
8. Add features
9. set networking type
10. start machine

And you can always Google it to find other resources.

- [Official source](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)
- [Unofficial source](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/)

Comment: Link only answers tend to deprecate over time. Please edit your answer as a step-by-step guide for the OP.

Comment: A step by step answer as you want would be impossible as the literature on this topic is much. Some effort on you part would have to be done. The official source is the most comprehensive place to start :).

Comment: It is not about effort on peoples part, link only answers are not allowed here. Please update this, some install instructions would do fine, just to flesh it out a bit. If those links go down, this answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Mark Kirby, ok will do so.

Comment: Let me know with a comment when you, I will give you a +1

Comment: @MarkKirby just added an updated hope it helps

Comment: @George Great answer!

Comment: @PatrickNegus, ok will do so

Comment: In step 4 i've got this error: `Syntax error: Invalid command 'modify'`

Comment: sorry @Cierra Clark its `modifyvm` not `modify` .

Comment: Now this error: `VBoxManage: error: 'Ubuntu10' is not a valid Guest OS type`

Comment: The original answer was perfectly fine. Please don't pay too much attention to comments; some people simply cannot understand that sometimes questions have a very simple answer.

Comment: @fkraiem, ok. Cierra make that `Ubuntu`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VirtualBox provides a `VBoxManage` utility that is quite exhaustive and can be used to manage headless installs.

Here's a nice reference: http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7673/
Official VirtualBox documentation: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html

Comment: @PatrickNegus This is not a link only answer; it correctly answers the question by saying that VirtualBox provides a command-line management tool called `VBoxManage`. A "step-by-step guide" was not asked, and anyway would depend on the exact desired VM configuration, which was not provided.

Comment: @PatrickNegus A link only answer is: "here's a link, the answer to your question is in there somewhere".

Comment: @Stormvirux: It's not link-only. See fkraiem's earlier comments for an explanation.

Comment: The question was poorly posed as "Is there any way to ... manage". It is unreasonable to expect an explicit answer to such a question, therefore, the only fair response would be to provide a reference to official documentation. Consuming the documentation then regurgitating it here is folly, most especially as command line invocations are likely to change from point release to point release making an example step-by-step of limited utility at best.